# how to schedule 1 timer in the application - service is not singleton?

Tags: angular, timer, rxjs, singleton, angular-services

I would like to make get request every X seconds. I've used a timer in a service constructor. The service is injected into a component that uses it.
I would like the service (as singleton) to schedule the get requests every X seconds - as one instance in the application, no matter how many browsers are routed to the component where the service is injected into. Currently - it seems like every new session is starting a new timer.
Update : After investigating I found out that the root cause for this is the fact that for some reason, the service is not singleton, although it is declared as @Injectible(
providedIn: 'root'
).
I even tried checking the subscribe : Subscription variable - to see if its already there - and when reaching it from a new route to the component (new browser) - it is undefined, so it didn't help.
This is my code:

The Service:

```js
@Injectible(
   providedIn: 'root'
)
export class MyService
{
    subscribe : Subscription; 
    dataSubject = new Subject<any>();
    datasubjectChanged : Observable<any> = this.dataSubject.asObservable();
    constructor(private httpClient : HttpClient)
    {
        if (!this.subscribe)
        {
           this.subscribe = timer(0, 10000)
            .pipe(
                switchMap(() => this.getData()
                .pipe(catchError(error =>
               {
                   return of ("problems in getting data");
               }
            )))).subscribe();
       }
    }
    
    getData(): Observable<any>
    {
        return this.httpClient.get<any>(<rlevantUrl>).
        pipe(response => 
        {
            this.dataSubject.next(response);
        }),
        catchError(err => {
            return throwError(err);
        })
    }
}
```

This is the component:

```js
export class Mycomponent(private mySrv : MyService)
{
    ngOnInit()
    {
        let sub = this.mySrv.datasubjectChanged.subscribe(result => dosomething(result)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean  by `no matter how many browsers are routed to the component where the service is injected into.`?

Comment: I mean that currently - when ever I routing to the component - it reaches the service constructor, and as so - setting a new timer with new repetitions.

Comment: again what do you mean `new browser`? how do you expect it to work?

Comment: I would expect the to have 1 instance of that service in the app, meaning - only 1 timer raises and work, working in the app scope. I event tried doing a check: if (!this.subscribe) - hoping it will know that the subscribe was already created - but its not. I need 1 timer (maybe even execute it somehow when bootstraping) - all the components that depend on that service - will be attached to the same timer

Answer (score 0):

Angular service by default is singleton in nature, and they are created when you route to a component where its injected into and its never destroyed.

Unless you are adding it in component's provider.

And if you want to `make get request every X seconds`, you could use `rxjs` `interval`

```
// RxJS v6+
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

//emit value in sequence every 1 second
const source = interval(1000);
//output: 0,1,2,3,4,5....
const subscribe = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

and basically make your http call in it.